# Time Machine (M1, MBP 2021) keeps failing across drives: "Failed to create volume info from disk 'missingURLForRemounting"

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, nas

I've been stumped by an issue with my time machine. Roughly 6 months ago all time machines backups stopped working across all HDDs I have:

- Two separate NAS Time machines
- Two separate external hard drives

It follows the same pattern:
It connects to the HDD / NAS, collects all changes, starts copying and then just fails silently at some point.

Looking at the logs, one error keeps popping up:

```
2023-07-03 12:08:31  Failed to create volume info from disk '<TMDisk: 0x11d01b800> '/System/Volumes/Data/home'', error: missingURLForRemounting
2023-07-03 12:08:38  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
```

Things I've tried: '

- Looked at all threads I could find online
- Deleted the TM backups and started them from scratch
- Used Ethernet connection
- Prevent MBP from sleep.
- Excluded more and more folders from the TM backups (no effect)

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this?

Comment: I think it's an issue with your source disk. Is there anything in `/System/Volumes/Data/home` ? Mine has r-x attributes for everyone; owned by root, wheel.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It looks fine to me:

dr-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    1 Jul  3 09:31 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 25 root  wheel  800 Jun 25 21:49 ..

Comment: You've got some extended attributes there, which I don't have. What does `ls -lae@ home` give?

Comment: Apologies, missed this. It adds: "purgeable-drecs-fixed   4" to the output above

Comment: I believe the first log message you posted (starting with "Failed to create") is normal/harmless.  This happens on my system when backups are successful